# SVG Fallback working in standards but not IE8, IE9 quirks

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG icon and a corresponding PNG icon.

My goal is to load SVG icon when the browser supports it and PNG icon when the browser doesn't support SVG(IE8, IE9-quirks) using SVG Fallback.

I also have a restriction that I should use only sprites.

I have built the sprites individually, no problems on that front.

Now I do the following.

for a span with class 'abc',

```
span.abc {
  background: url(sprite.png) bg-posn-x bg-posn-y;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url(sprite.svg) bg-posn-x bg-posn-y;
  width: npx;
  height: npx;
}
```

The trick is that browsers that don't support rgba fall back to the previous background delcaration.

This works perfectly in standards, but not ie8, ie9 quirks.

Unfortunately, I should not convert my page to standards.

Did anyone face this issue previously/ know how to solve it?

Comment: What the hell is `bg-posn-x bg-posn-y`? Thats not valid! Use `top`, `center`, `bottom`, `left` or Pixel/percentage values. For repeating use `no-repeat` or `repeat-x`, `repeat-y`

Comment: IE9 quirks is basically IE7, you are probably hitting a whole load of other issues at that point.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I was mentioning the pixel values. My apologies that it didn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like Modernizer to do feature detection to get around this, relying on browser fallback can be a pain in the butt sometimes. Check here: http://modernizr.com/docs/

It will add classes to the body like "no-rgba" so you will know when to do a work around.

Comment: sure, will take a look.